# Why can't Firefox snap open other apps or downloads?

Tags: 22.04, firefox, snap

I am having an issue whereby Firefox is unable to open other apps. If I have an app that requires a browser to do an SSO login (e.g. Element), Firefox will not prompt to redirect back to the app after login, while other browsers will.

Similarly, I cannot open any downloads from Firefox, or use the "Open containing folder" link to open the Downloads folder in the file manager.

When I start Firefox from the command line, I see this message:

```
Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

(firefox-beta:1049863): Gdk-WARNING **: 11:28:14.133: Failed to read portal settings: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.Settings” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop
```

Then, when I click "Open containing folder" in the Downloads dialogue, I see this message:

```
Failed to query file manager via OpenDirectory: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.OpenURI” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop
[Parent 1049863, Main Thread] WARNING: Cannot launch default application: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.OpenURI” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: 'glib warning', file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp:167

** (firefox-beta:1049863): WARNING **: 11:28:21.989: Cannot launch default application: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.OpenURI” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop
```

It seems like there is some component missing here to do with the desktop portal. I have the following related packages installed:

```
xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/jammy-updates,now 42.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
xdg-desktop-portal-gtk/jammy,now 1.14.0-1build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xdg-desktop-portal/jammy-updates,now 1.14.4-1ubuntu2~22.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

This is Ubuntu 22.04. I have tried this on XOrg and Wayland, with the current stable and beta channels of the Firefox snap. I have also tried disabling extensions, and tried a new Firefox profile, all with no effect.

Comment: Is there anything in the journal or dmesg when you try this? Any apparmor messages? Leave `sudo dmesg -Tw` running when you try.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a reboot this started working. I'm not sure exactly what did it, but I suspect that installing `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` then doing the reboot contributed.